# Binding functions with attributes

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Is there a way to bind functions with attributes, something like this:

```
<a _href="{{go('login')}}">Login</a>
```

then

```
String go(String routePath) {
  // Returns url for login
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For routing task, you may bind using additional attribute for path:

```
<a route="/api/login" on-tap="{{go}}">
```

and then, in your go function:

```
void go(Event e, var detail, Element sender) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fire('change-route', detail: sender.attributes['route'] );
}
```